# How to create a script that will connect to a specific network

Tags: networking, scripts, network-manager, vpn

Using the integrated Network Manager, I created a new VPN Connection, called 'My VPN'. When I click it, it connects - great.

Now I need to automate it a bit. Is it possible to write a script which will connect to that specific connection by name, or whatever? Once it's connected, I want to start up my browser...

Using Ubuntu 14 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the credentials in the connection configuration file, look for a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` called "MyVPN" and add the following section:

```
[vpn-secrets]
password=my_vpn_password
```

Then add `password-flags=0` and `secret-flags=0` into the `[vpn]` section.

Now you can easily create a connection to your new VPN with [`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html):

```
nmcli con up id 'My VPN'
```

Note that you may need to open the VPN configuration from the NetworkManager applet and save it from there to allow command-line connections.

Comment: If I do this, I get Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets.

Comment: @drminnaar Please try with `sudo nmcli con up id 'My VPN'`

Comment: nope, same problem.

Comment: @drminnaar Try after adding the [vpn-secrets] section to the connection config file

Comment: Actually, this seems to be a problem with the login keyring. I'm not using a password to login. Not sure what now?

Comment: @drminnaar: I've added a two options to add in the [vpn] section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18289/discussion-between-drminnaar-and-sylvain-pineau).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to type this script:

```
 [Default]

 networkmanger="true"
 nmcli nm network=(name of network) vpn
 firefox
```

and it might work fine this way.